# neo4J graph query generator

Tags: neo4j, automation, graph-databases

I was looking for the feature to generate some graph queries in neo4j.
As the database size is huge so can anyone suggest the procedure to generate small queries (3-5 nodes a -> b -> c ->a).
I can run BFS from a node but how can I find the small graph containing only a specific number of nodes as graph structure?

> ```
>    a
>  /   \
> b-----c----d
> ```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to find only "disjoint subgraphs" that have a specific number of nodes?

Comment: Yah. Actually I want to generate graph like queries having a specific number of nodes. But it not mandatory that the generated subgraphs are disjoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UPDATED]

If you want to get a single arbitrary path of length 4 (having 4 relationships and 5 nodes), and you do not need the path to be unidirectional, then you can simply do this:

```
MATCH p=()-[*4]-()
RETURN p
LIMIT 1;
```

If you want the path to be unidirectional (where all relationships point in the same direction), then you just need to specify a direction:

```
MATCH p=()-[*4]->()
RETURN p
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the ans. But, I am actually looking some graph structure. This match and limit is returning only the n relations.
       a
     /   \
  b----c----d

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It gave me an idea.